# Add my Android app to the "send via" menu

Tags: java, android

I use the [OSMand Navi app](http://osmand.net/). In there I want to click on a point a hit the Share button. Then there is a list of apps I can send the coordinates to.

I want my app being in that list. I read about it and added an `<intent-filter>` to my *AndroidManifest.xml*.

```
<application        
    <activity
        android:name=".MyMainActivity"
        android:label="My App" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
```

But my app is still not on the list. I even tried to reinstall it and restarted my phone.

Comment: can you try  `android.intent.action.SEND` instead of `android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT` ? its default for `share intent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Share" is usually implemented [via `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html), not `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: Now it works  when using `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />` instead of `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` like it is described in the link you posted.